# Add toolbar to decimal keyboard with next and previous button in alert controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertcontroller, uitoolbar, custom-keyboard

I have the following function that adds next and previous buttons that will switch between textfields to allow a better user experience. However I am not able to implement this through the textfields that are within the alert controller. Is there a solution or must I think of another design for my app?

```
extension UIViewController {
func addInputAccessoryForTextFields(textFields: [UITextField], dismissable: Bool = true, previousNextable: Bool = false) {
    for (index, textField) in textFields.enumerated() {
        let toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        if previousNextable {
            let previousButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "previous"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            previousButton.width = 30
            if textField == textFields.first {
                previousButton.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                previousButton.target = textFields[index - 1]
                previousButton.action = #selector(UITextField.becomeFirstResponder)
            }
            let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "next"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
            nextButton.width = 30
            if textField == textFields.last {
                nextButton.isEnabled = false
            } else {
                nextButton.target = textFields[index + 1]
                nextButton.action = #selector(UITextField.becomeFirstResponder)
            }
            items.append(contentsOf: [previousButton, nextButton])
        }
        let spacer = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        items.append(contentsOf: [spacer, doneButton])
        toolbar.setItems(items, animated: false)
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }
}
}
```

And this is my alert controller where I am declaring the alerts and adding them:

```
alertDisplay.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Team 1 Score"
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad

    }
    alertDisplay.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter Team 2 Score"
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    }
```

To call the function I must add the textfields that I want in the array (which will allow the next and previous to go through textfields). This function is called within the viewDidLoad() method.

So the question is how can I make the two textfields within the alert to have this custom toolbar for the keyboard?

Comment: I would recommend using a custom view as an alert instead, since this level of customization is much easier that way.

Comment: @the4kman I have never thought about that. Was so stupid to realize! Thank you.